# How to handle exceptions inside controller in symfony2 framework

Tags: symfony, error-handling, doctrine-orm

I am trying to catch exceptions inside an Action in a Controller in Symfony2.3 application during entity persistance.

```
 try {
            $em->persist($firm);
     } catch(\Exception $e){
             .........
     }
```

I expected that all errors will be handled by my code inside *catch* statement, instead I got following errors:

```
[2/2] DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO ...
...
[1/2] PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
...
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
```

If I throw exception inside *try* statement it is cought and handled properly by code inside *catch*

```
try {
           throw new \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException;
           //or throw new \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;
           //or throw new \PDOException;
    } catch(\Exception $e){
      .......        
    }
```

My question is: **How one should properly handle Doctrine2 inside Symfony2 controller.**
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible that you have got exception from line `$em->flush()` which doesnt wrapped with try-catch statement.

Comment: that's the first thing that came to my mind. `persist()` does not actually executes any sql. It has to come from `flush()`. So you should wrap the `flush()` call in your `try` statement too.

Comment: Yes. That was the reason. My bad!
Thank you forgottenbas, Florian, nifr.

Answer (score 3):

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

In your case you should check for uniqueness **before** persisting your entity using the [UniqueEntity validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html).

If the form does not validate - just don't persist in order to avoid this exception.

Comment: Thanks! That is a helpful hint. I will go in that direction if I cannot figure it out with try-catch block.